# War Deployment error in Grails

Tags: grails, tomcat6, war

i am using grails 2.1.1 version and tomcat 6.0, while when i am deploying the war file i am getting the exception like this:

```
2012-12-11 12:20:03,891 [main] ERROR context.ContextLoader  - Context initialization failed
        org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 4 in XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Document root element "beans", must match DOCTYPE root "null".
        org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Document root element "beans", must match DOCTYPE root "null".
```

At

```
at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(Unknown Source)
            at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(Unknown Source)
            at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
            at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
            at org.apache.xerces.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.rootElementSpecified(Unknown Source)
            at org.apache.xerces.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.handleStartElement(Unknown Source)
            at org.apache.xerces.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.startElement(Unknown Source)
            at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(Unknown Source)
            at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$ContentDispatcher.scanRootElementHook(Unknown Source)
            at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDispatcher.dispatch(Unknown Source)
            at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
            at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
            at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
            at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
            at org.apache.xerces.parsers.DOMParser.parse(Unknown Source)
            at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:222)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:173)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:148)
```

any body have idea is a great helpful.

Thanks.

arnagendla

Comment: Well I don't mean to state the obvious but a file seems to be currpt, try cleaning, refreshing, and do a new grails war...

Comment: I done refresh, grails clean, there after also same expception.

Comment: i am using these lines in applicationContext.xmlfile           **<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd">**

Answer (score 0):

Check if an older version of Spring libraries exists in tomcat. The error message

> org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Document root element "beans", must
>   match DOCTYPE root "null".

indicates that there is some kind of version mismatch between the DTD used, and the supplied libraries

Comment: Thanks **Enterlezi** , I cleaned Entire Grails ivy-cache and run the application. in this case also same result. can you tell me the dtd and libraries for grails 2.1.1 version.

Comment: and also giving the error **INFO: validateJarFile(E:\apache-tomcat-6.0.32-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-6.0.32\webapps\admin\WEB-INF\lib\tomcat-embed-core-7.0.30.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 2.3, section 9.7.2. Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class** . any idea?

Comment: I think that grails 2.1 has spring 3.0, so i think that your configuration should be xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd" (can not actually test it right now)

Comment: thanks **enterlezi** . but this one also same problem. by default 2.5.xsd will generating with grails 2,1,1 version.

Comment: it will giving   **2012-12-13 17:11:54,263 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR context.ContextLoader  - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 5 in XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Document root element "beans", must match DOCTYPE root "null".
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Document root element "beans", must match DOCTYPE root "null".**  how to add same version of dtd Bean to xml file? have any idea?